# How to match pairs and merge data frame by values in two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
x    y    val
A    B    5
A    C    3
B    A    7
B    C    9
C    A    1
```

As you can see there are two pairs matching by `x` and `y`:

Pair 1: `A B 5` and `B A 7`

Pair 2: `A C 3` and `C A 1`

I would like to merge them to `A B 12` and `A C 4` and leave the `B C 9` as it doesn't have a pair (`C B`).

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
x    y    val
A    B    12
A    C    4
B    C    9
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(var = paste(pmin(x, y), pmax(x, y))) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(val))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   var     val
>   <chr> <int>
> 1 A B      12
> 2 A C       4
> 3 B C       9
> ```

Add `separate(var, c("x", "y"))` to the end of the chain if you want the `x` and `y` columns as Melissa Key mentions.

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that `x` and `y` are character giving `DF_c` and then sort them giving `DF_s`.  Finally perform the aggregation.  No packages are used.  The first line would not be needed if `x` and `y` were already character.

```
DF_c <- transform(DF, x = as.character(x), y = as.character(y))
DF_s <- transform(DF_c, x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y))
aggregate(val ~ x + y, DF_s, sum)
```

giving:

```
  x y val
1 A B  12
2 A C   4
3 B C   9
```

Answer (score 0):

One can group by `row_number()` to `sort` and combine columns in sorted order to create a order independent `pair`.

**Note:** Below solution can be evolve to work for more than 2 columns pairing as well. e.g.treating `A B C`, `A C B` or `B C A` as same group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(row_number()) %>%
  mutate(xy = paste0(sort(c(x,y)),collapse=",")) %>%
  group_by(xy) %>%
  summarise(val = sum(val)) %>% 
  separate(xy, c("x","y"))

## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  x     y       val
#* <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 A     B        12
#2 A     C         4
#3 B     C         9
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"x    y    val
A    B    5
A    C    3
B    A    7
B    C    9
C    A    1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```